# Spring Cloud Gateway Fallback on 404 Status Code from route

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to go to the fallback when any of the routes return 404 HTTP Code. The reason is that if a resource is not found, the route should try to fetch that from the fallback Uri.

Following is my .yml defined. What I am trying to achieve is if the elastic search didn't find my record and returns 404. Search in fallback i.e. database. But I am getting 404 from the gateway in this case. Is there any way to achieve this.?

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway

  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0

  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true

        - id: search_route
          uri: lb://ELASTIC_SEARCH_SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/unison/search/**
          filters:
            - name: Hystrix
              args:
                name: fallbackCommand
                fallbackUri: forward:/search/rdbms
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make the gateway aware of the eureka server with this

**eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://user:pass@localhost:8761/eureka**

And then prevent the gateway from registerin itself to eureka

**eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false**

The second option is important as it causes 404 errors with loadbalancing using lb:servicename structure.